# How to avoid triggering workflow on create when creating items through csom

Tags: sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, csom

I have a SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow that needs to be run on create. 
This workflow calls a Web Service method I have created, that creates a whole folder structure inside the folder that triggered the call. 
I want the new folders to NOT KICK the workflows on create. I thought running as System Account would do the trick, however the workflows still triggered. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Folder is also an item as per design but with different content type. You cannot avoid triggering of workflow but what you can do is check in your workflow on top if Content Type is folder, exit workflow without doing anything. Or you can create a hidden column, update this column only when item is created from CSOM and check in workflow if this hidden column has value, exit workflow. If not, do the processing.

Comment: Is there no way of creating the item from CSOM as System Account, I was under the impression that workflows don't run as system account but when I tried to run the context under system account network credentials the workflows still triggered..?

Comment: CSOM does not run under system account, it runs under user's account which is treated as normal user though user is system account. this is due to fact that CSOM is designed to perform only certain certain of actions in farm.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an condition to check if created by System account and if so then stop WF.